# Forcing inconsitency by following qualified cardinality restriction

Tags: ontology, owl, protege

My question goes beyond one question which already has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551280/qualified-cardinality-restriction-definition-in-protege)

I defined a qualified cardinality restriction like this one:

```
Pizza and hasTopping exactly 4 CheeseTopping and hasTopping only CheeseTopping
```

Now, how do I force inconsistency of the ontology when having an individual of asserted type 'FourCheesePizza' with less than four 'CheeseTopping' property assertions?

In other words: How do I state that the let us say two 'CheeseTopping' property assertions are definitely the only ones so that an inconsistency is forced?

Answer (score 1):

Making a statement like that is not too difficult in OWL, but because of the [open world assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_world_assumption), it does mean that you have to make sure that a bit more knowledge is available.  First, the two-cheese-pizza, let's call it *p*, that will be inconsistently labelled a four-cheese-pizza must somehow be declared to have *exactly* two cheese toppings.  You can do this by giving *p* the type

> hasTopping **exactly** 2 CheeseTopping .

This would be enough to get the inconsistency.  If that seems a bit generic, and you want to specify the exact toppings that *p* can have, you could give *p* a type like

> hasTopping **only** { Cheddar, Mozzarella }

which says that *p* can only have *Cheddar* and *Mozzarella* as toppings.  At this point, we know that *p* can have at most two toppings (it could be just one, if *Cheddar* and *Mozzarella* haven't been declared to be different individuals), which is inconsistent with it being a *FourCheesePizza* and having four cheese toppings.